# Issue In Barcode font 128 C c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, barcode

i am using Barcode 128 C font and using IDAutomation library for convert number into barcode font. here is cs code for conversion my number into barcode.Input value is 009198

```
        public string Code128C(string InputValue)
    {
        char Code128CStartChar;         //start character for Code 128A
        char Code128CStopChar;          //stop character for Code 128A
        char Code128CCheckDigit;        //check digit for Code 128A
        string EncodedData = "";        //This is the encoded data that we wwill return
        int idx = 0;                    //for loop counter, to loop thru characters passed in
        int WeightedTotal = 0;          //used to get weighted total of characters for check digit
        int LenDataToEncode = 0;        //Len of string passed in
        char[] InputData;               //Character array of input string passed in, so that we can evaluate each charactr
        string GoodData = "";           //This is the good data from the InputValue, once we strip out dashes
        int iCurrentChars;              //The integer value of the 2 characters we are currently working with
        string sCurrentChars;           //The sting representation of the 2 characters we are working with.
        int WeightFactor = 0;           //used to calculate the check digit
        /* Here we select character set C.  We can simply convert the ASCII value to a character
         * by casting it as a char type */
        Code128CStartChar = (char) ASCII_START128_C;
        Code128CStopChar = (char) ASCII_STOP128;            
        /* <<<< Calculate Modulo 103 Check Digit >>>> */
        /* Set WeightedTotal to the value of the start character */
        WeightedTotal = ASCII_START128_C - 100;
        LenDataToEncode = InputValue.Length;
        InputData = InputValue.ToCharArray();
        //First check to make sure data is number and remove and dashes
        for(idx=0; idx < LenDataToEncode; idx++)
        {
            if((Char.IsNumber(InputData[idx])) == false)
            {
                //make sure it is not a dash.  If it is a dash, remove it, otherwise get out of the function
                if(InputData[idx] != '-')
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                GoodData = GoodData + InputData[idx];
            }
        }           
        if((GoodData.Length % 2) != 0)
            GoodData = "0" + GoodData;
        //Calculate Mod 103 Weighted total check digit value, using only the Good Data
        LenDataToEncode = GoodData.Length;
        WeightFactor = 1;
        for(idx=0; idx < LenDataToEncode; idx = idx + 2)
        {
            /* Get the value of the current character plus the next */
            sCurrentChars = GoodData.Substring(idx,2);
            iCurrentChars = Convert.ToInt32(sCurrentChars);

            //Multiply by the weighting value and add it to the total
            WeightedTotal = WeightedTotal + (iCurrentChars * WeightFactor);
            WeightFactor = WeightFactor + 1;

            //Let's calculate the weighted total.
            if(iCurrentChars < 95 && iCurrentChars > 0)
                iCurrentChars = iCurrentChars + 32;
            else if(iCurrentChars > 94)
                iCurrentChars = iCurrentChars + 100;
            else if(iCurrentChars == 0) 
                iCurrentChars = ASCII_SPACE_CHAR;

            //Set the return value
            EncodedData = EncodedData + (char) iCurrentChars;
        }
        /* divide the WeightedTotal by 103 and get the remainder,  this is the CheckDigitValue*/            
        iCurrentChars = WeightedTotal % 103;

        /* Now that we have the CheckDigitValue, find the corresponding ASCII character
        from the table */
        if(iCurrentChars < 95 && iCurrentChars > 0) 
            iCurrentChars = iCurrentChars + 32;
        else if(iCurrentChars > 94) 
            iCurrentChars = iCurrentChars + 100;
        else if(iCurrentChars == 0) 
            iCurrentChars = ASCII_SPACE_CHAR;
        //Convert the ASCII value to the character representation.
        Code128CCheckDigit = (char) iCurrentChars;
        /* Return the EncodedData */
        EncodedData = Code128CStartChar + EncodedData + Code128CCheckDigit + Code128CStopChar;
        return EncodedData;
    } //End Code 128C
```

Above is my code to convert number into barcode and i install font code128 for displaying in report but barcode is creating issue here is screenshot attached.
[image]

At the end this font is returned by code "ÍÂ|ÂsÎ" output

Comment: It looks like 2 of the characters are out of scope of the font characters. Maybe your algorithm for encoding has a bug.

Comment: in above code algorithm has mentioned can you modify this?

Comment: Or maybe your input is wrong? You know the rule: garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Can you show an example input ? Im thinking the >94 is where your issue lies - or ANSI_SPACE_CHAR maybe? there are a number of ASCII<something>s that arent defined in your code snippet so..

Comment: @BugFinder this is input 009198

Comment: it selevt ascii character 294 which is ~A

Comment: then can you show if you display sCurrentChars  and iCurrentChars  at each itteration what exactly its picking up at each round?

Comment: ok wait let me show you characters which are generated

Comment: i have updated my question with output which encoded data returned @BugFinder

Comment: that only appears to be half the answer - and given that 91+100 on my machine doesnt equal the same character you have, the numbers would be useful

Comment: its full code @BugFinder

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)